# Using functools lru_cache, how can I determine if the function returned me cached data?

Tags: python, lru

I have a simple implementation using the wrapper lru_cache around a function that fetches data from a remote database. I want to be able to tell if the result might be "stale" (i.e., it was fetched from the cache vs from the database). How can I figure that out?

Code is simple, just:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=2048)
def fetch_cached_data(query, *args, **kwargs):
    return fetch_data(query, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

A poor solution, valid only in a **single-threaded** program, could be to monitor the `cache_info` of the function to see if the statistics are changing:

```
hits = f.cache_info().hits
result = f(some_arg)
if f.cache_info().hits > hits:
    # this result was retrieved from cache
    ...
```

A better solution might be to think more about what you consider *stale* ... all the values have ultimately come from the database ... what makes one that you queried in a past function call stale ... the time since it was last queried, a version stamp on the rows returned etc

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `ring`, valid only in single-threaded program.

```py
import ring

@ring.lru(maxsize=2048)
def fetch_cached_data(query, *args, **kwargs):
    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_cached = fetch_cached_data.has('query')
    data = fetch_cached_data('query')
    print(is_cached, data)

    is_cached = fetch_cached_data.has('query')
    data = fetch_cached_data('query')
    print(is_cached, data)
```

Then output is:

```
False query
True query
```